# Power BI Dashboards - create visuals without pinning them

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI we can create visuals in two different ways - 1) By creating reports, 2) By creating dashboards.

By creating reports means building the visuals from scratch - choosing the appropriate dataset and visual, applying filters, formatting etc. By dashboards, there is an option to pin visuals form different reports to the dashboard canvas. But it also sets many limitations because we cannot combine the data from different reports.

For example, we have pinned 3 card visuals to the dashboard showing selling numbers from 3 different sales departments (every department has it's own report). Now we want to show these numbers also in timeline by creating the line visual (where all departments numbers are shown together over the years). But we don't have this kind of visual in any of these 3 reports and therefore cannot pin it.

So, is it possible to create this kind of visual to the dashboard without pinning it? I mean, at first pinning 3 card visuals and then (analogously to reports) creating from scratch (choosing dataset etc) this line visual?

Comment: As per my knowledge, the answer is no. You have to create a new report first pointing all data sources together. Then you can create the line chart you are talking abut and then share/see it using dashboard.

Comment: Have you tried the Q&A function? You can ask the question, and specify the chart type to display it in.

Comment: The main issue here seems to be "every department has it's own report". Similar data from all the departments would normally be gathered into one report. That design would also have a lot less duplication in the report and query design, and avoid inconsistent logic.